# Mailing form data with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fetch-api

I'm trying to use Fetch API to retrieve data from form and mail it, but the email I'm receiving is empty. The response seems to be successful, but no data being sent. What am I doing wrong?

This is my JS code and my php/html snippet if it's relevant

```js
(function() {

  const submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');

  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', postData);

  function postData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const first_name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
    const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    const message = document.querySelector('#msg').value;

    fetch('process.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({first_name:first_name, email:email, message:message})
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      // Success
    });

  }

})();



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<?php 
    $to = "example@mail.com"; 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $from = $_POST['email']; 
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = "Test Email";
    $message = $first_name . " sent a message:" . "\n\n" . $message;
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>


<form action="" method="post" class="contact__form form" id="contact-form">
  <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" name="first_name" required="">
  <input type="email" class="form__input" placeholder="Email address" id="email" name="email" required="">
  <textarea id="msg" placeholder="Message" class="form__textarea" name="message"/></textarea>
  <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP does not understand JSON request bodies. So when JSON text is sent to it, PHP will not automatically parse the JSON and put the data into the global $_POST variable.

Also `fetch()` will use the default mime text/plain for content-type when the body is just text. So even if you set `body` to the data in say the format of `x-www-form-urlencoded` it will not set the request header to the correct one and PHP won't parse it correctly.

You either have to manually get the sent data and parse it yourself:

```
<?php

$dataString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($dataString);
echo $data->first_name;
```

Send the data as a different content type, ie `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by explicitly setting the content-type header and passing the correct formatted `body`:

```
fetch('/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers:{
    "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  body: "first_name=name&email=email@example.com"
})
```

Or even create a `FormData` object and let fetch automatically detect the correct content-type to use:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('first_name','name');
data.append('email','email@example.com');

fetch('/', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
```